# Problem with Psaxes after update

Tags: errors, pstricks, update

The following MWE is an extract from a bigger file which worked fine for a long time. After a miktex-update on thursday, I always get the same error. Compiling with `LaTeX->PDF` in TeXniCenter.

[image]

If I add a `%` in front of `\psaxes`, the error disappears. Since `pstricks` was updated on thursday, I suspect there might be a problem within the package?!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,DIV=15,oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begingroup
\catcode`\#=11
\gdef\autorotatonone{-dAutoRotatePages#/None}
\endgroup
\usepackage[pspdf={\autorotatonone}]{auto-pst-pdf}

\psset{unit=1cm,algebraic,subgriddiv=2,gridlabels=0pt,gridwidth=0.4pt,subgridwidth=0.4pt,gridcolor=black!50,subgridcolor=black!50,algebraic=true}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(7,3)
\psgrid(0,-1)(7,3)
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(0,-1)(7,3)[\small $t$ in s,0][\small $I$ in A,90]
\psline[linecolor=red](0,-1)(2,2)(4,0)(5,1.5)(6,1.5)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: My distribution is up-to-date, and I have no problem with this code…

Comment: I'll update a new version. Until then try http://comedy.dante.de/~herbert/texnik/dvips/pstricks/pstricks.pro it should fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is file `pstricks.pro` with the conversion from polar to cartesian. `PtoC360` should be `PtoC` and `PtoC` should be `PtoCrel`:

```
/PtoC { 2 copy cos mul 3 1 roll sin mul } def % Polar to Cartesian (original)
/PtoCrel { pst@angleunit 2 copy cos mul 3 1 roll sin mul } def % Polar to Cartesian
```

Comment: Works fine, thank you very much for your quick reply!